# Alignment issues due to vspace and hfill

Tags: vertical-alignment

Facing issues with alignment (the 3 and 4 are out of alignment), I suspect it has to do with the vspace and hfill issue. Please assist.

```
\begin{enumerate}[\textbf{(\roman*)}]
\item Using a scale of 1 cm to 0.1 unit on each axis, plot $\lg y$ against $\lg x$ and draw a straight line graph. \hfill [3]
\item Use your graph to estimate the value of $k$ and of $n$. \hfill [4]
\vspace{\baselineskip}\newline\vspace{0.000001cm} \hfill [$k=84.2$, $n=1.35$]
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: alignment issues]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply adding a blank line instead of applying a `\vspace` will resolve the issue:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Using a scale of 1 cm to 0.1 unit on each axis, plot $\lg y$ against $\lg x$ and draw a straight line graph. \hfill [3]
\item Use your graph to estimate the value of $k$ and of $n$. \hfill [4]

\hfill [$k=84.2$, $n=1.35$]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

this looks like a situation where `\\` (after the `[4]`) is actually justifiable:

```
\item Use your graph to estimate the value of $k$ and of $n$. \hfill [4]\\
\hfill [$k=84.2$, $n=1.35$]
```